# Delete artifacts and their entire directory from maven local repository

Tags: maven, repository, artifacts, purge

I am trying to delete old artifacts and the directory they live in from my .m2/repository directory. For example I have several versions of projectA:
4.7.0.222, 4.7.0.223, 4.7.0.224 etc. I only need to keep 4.7.0.224 project since it is the latest build.

How can I remove the older 2 versions 4.7.0.222 and 4.7.0.223 without manually deleting them? I have tried this command:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DreResolve=false -DactTransitively=false -Dverbose=true
```

When I was in those project directories, everything was successful, but the items still remained. Does maven have any commands that are similar to a full linux "rm -rf" or No?

Answer (score 1):

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html#The_dependency:purge-local-repository_mojo

**dependency:purge-local-repository**

> [...]
>
> This goal is meant to delete all of the **dependencies** for the current project (or projects, in the case of a multimodule build) from the local repository.
>
> [...]

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/purging-local-repository.html#Other_purge_configuration

> [...]
>
> To purge **all** the dependencies of a given *groupId*, use the `resolutionFuzziness` configuration parameter.
>
> If neither includes nor excludes are specified, all the dependencies of the current project are purged.
>
> [...]
>
> - **file** - Delete just the artifact's file.
> - **version** - Delete the version directory containing this artifact.
> - **artifactId** - Delete the artifactId directory containing this artifact.
> - **groupId** - Delete the groupId directory structure containing this artifact.
>
> To add the restriction that the *[...]* artifact not be deleted, add the `exclude` parameter as a comma-delimited list of groupId:artifactId pairs.